# how to redirect a page in React after clicking on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

im trying to redirect the page after the user is logged in but I cant

i want to redirect it to another page components inside the project so `window` solution wont work for me

here is my code:

```
function toggleSignIn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
          alert("Wrong password.");
        } else {
          alert(errorMessage);
        }
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  <button
                  to="CardsTabs"
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={toggleSignIn}
                >
                  Giriş Yap
                </button>
```

noting that i cant use `Link` becasue it wont be working the firebase auth.

how can i achieve it?

i have tried multpile solutions but them seem old

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router) as well?

Comment: yes and tried it but it is not working for me I guess because old

Answer (score 0):

If login succeeded - you can use navigate using [`react-router`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial)'s [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook:

```
const navigate = useNavigate("www.your-url.com");
```

You can also do the below, but it will cause a browser refresh, meaning that any state data will be lost:

```
window.location.href = "www.your-url.com";
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i want it to navigate to another page component in the same project

Comment: react-router is your friend. Read how to integrate it in your project and then use "useNavigate" hook.